# Where does this design of a monster come from?

Tags: animation, the-arctic-giant

In the 1942 Superman cartoon *The Arctic Giant* there is a monster which picture I am including in this question. In the cartoon, it is described as a tyrannosaurus. Where does the design of this monster come from? I initially thought it could be a Godzilla ripoff, however, *Godzilla* premiered 12 years later. So is this how people believed dinosaurs looked like in 1942 or is this design based on something else - like only the artistic vision of the artists?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The monster doesn't look like the depiction of a tyrannosaurus in 1940s science nor like the modern depiction of a tyrannosaurus.

About the only thing this monster has in common with a real tyrannosaurus is being reptilian, bipedal, and very large, much larger than real tyrannosaurus.  More like an imaginary *Tyrannosaurus imperator* than a real*Tyrannosaurus rex*.

So I would say that the monster is more or less based on a highly exaggerated popular image of a generic meat eating dinosaur made many times larger than in real life.